# CloudKit offline storage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, cloudkit

I'm developing iOS app which is using CloudKit. I'm pretty clear how to download/upload data from cloud when requested on the device. It works just fine when internet connection is present. I'm thinking to allow users to access their data offline also. After brief research I discovered that CoreData integration with iCloud was depreciated as of recent Xcode release. I found some third party pods on github which let you handle this problem by syncing core data from device to iCloud. I'm a bit skeptical using those plugins due to possible data loss or other issues. Is the idea behind depreciating CloudKit to move away from offline storage?  Im thinking now what to do... should I attempt to create some sort of sync between core data and iCloud or not use core data at all and just let users to access data only when online connection available. Such approach would save device storage but restrict data access to online only. Any recommendations ?

Comment: CloudKit is not deprecated. Core Data's integration with iCloud is deprecated, but that's not the same thing. Core Data has never had any integration with CloudKit, so there's nothing to deprecate there.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant "integration with iCloud" CloudKit is part of iCould. I'm not sure why you say there's nothing to depreciate. Anyways, you have any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html

Comment: @KirillC I believe you are correct, have been looking at the very same, the guide is just really really bad. If you are ready to use a third party library, perhaps EVCloudKitDao (https://cocoapods.org/pods/EVCloudKitDao) looks promising, though I haven't tried it. However, it allows caching, which may be what you need, though it does not mention offline capability explicitly.

Comment: An alternative is to use iCloud key-value storage (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html), it's kinda like using NSUserDefaults but in iCloud, so if you are familiar with that, then it is quite easy to handle and it will automatically cache when offline and sync across devices when the user is online again. The downside though is that you can only have very limited and simple data (think app settings), and the sync is not instantaneously, it is handled automatically by iCloud in the backgorund.

Comment: Or perhaps YapDatabase (https://cocoapods.org/pods/YapDatabase).

Answer (score 1):

CoreData integration with iCloud is not depreciated, here are some references from Apple:

- [Setting up core data with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit)
- [Syncing a core data store with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit)
- [Mirroring a core data store with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit)
- [WWDC 2019 - Using Core Data With CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/202/)